# Symfony 3 new project error [GuzzleHttp Exception]

Tags: php, symfony

I'm on OpenSUSE Leap 42.1 and I installation went without any issues. But when I tried to create new Symfony project running command

```
symfony new project
```

I get 2 following exceptions inside the terminal:

```
[GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException]                                          
  No system CA bundle could be found in any of the the common system locations.    
  PHP versions earlier than 5.6 are not properly configured to use the system's    
  CA bundle by default. In order to verify peer certificates, you will need to     
  supply the path on disk to a certificate bundle to the 'verify' request          
  option: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/clients.html#verify. If you do not   
  need a specific certificate bundle, then Mozilla provides a commonly used CA     
  bundle which can be downloaded here (provided by the maintainer of cURL):        
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt. Once    
  you have a CA bundle available on disk, you can set the 'openssl.cafile' PHP     
  ini setting to point to the path to the file, allowing you to omit the 'verify'  
  request option. See http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html for more              
  information.                                                                     






  [RuntimeException]                                                               
  No system CA bundle could be found in any of the the common system locations.    
  PHP versions earlier than 5.6 are not properly configured to use the system's    
  CA bundle by default. In order to verify peer certificates, you will need to     
  supply the path on disk to a certificate bundle to the 'verify' request          
  option: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/clients.html#verify. If you do not   
  need a specific certificate bundle, then Mozilla provides a commonly used CA     
  bundle which can be downloaded here (provided by the maintainer of cURL):        
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt. Once    
  you have a CA bundle available on disk, you can set the 'openssl.cafile' PHP     
  ini setting to point to the path to the file, allowing you to omit the 'verify'  
  request option. See http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html for more              
  information.
```

I read on symfony github that I need to download [this certificate](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) but when I open it, it says that it's already installed.

**Edit:** Php version is 5.5.14

Comment: Maybe it helps you: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-installer/issues/237#issuecomment-204443637

Comment: @malcolm Yes I already saw that and it didn't work for me. I did reset the apache afterwards but didn't help. I know the issue will be gone if I use 5.6 php but it's not marked as stable yet on OpenSUSE Leap so I'm trying to fix this for 5.5.14 somehow

Comment: So yeah, we are using PHP 7.0 stable and you will use what suse have to offer you, I don't keep up with your logic.

Comment: @malcolm I'm sorry, but I've read the official documentation of Symfony and I have read that it requires 5.5.9 PHP version, so I was wondering how can I go around of this and I'm pretty sure many newbies would be stuck on this without finding a real solution beside upgrading to newer PHP.

Comment: Want to use Symfony 3 - upgrade PHP to meet Symfony requirements. Look around, if you want to use for ex. JQuery plugin, you need to have JQuery minimum version required by plugin, otherwise it's not working. So simple.

Comment: Ok then, I'll consider upgrading PHP as a solution.